# understanding synchronizedlist in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, java-threads

I having an ArrayList which is modified by one thread and read by another. 
Reading thread is happy to read whatever is left in the list after modification. It should stop when all the items are removed from the list.
It is mentioned in the java doc of Collections.synchronizedList() that we should manually synchronize the list before performing any operations on it.

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
>   list when iterating over it:
>
> List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
>         ...   synchronized (list) {
>         Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
>         while (i.hasNext())
>             foo(i.next());   }   Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior.

but on synchronizing, it keeps on reading till the end of data before it gives a chance to the other thread modify the list. (Yes, because the list is locked).

```
package test.thread.concurrency.synchronizedlist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class Solution {
     private List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
    //private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // private CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public Solution() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            list.add("Item_" + i);
        }
    }

    private void removeItemsFromList() {
        synchronized (list) {
            System.out.println("Removing: " + list.remove(0));
        }
    }

    private void readFromLIst() {

        synchronized (list) {
            Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("READ: "+ it.next());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Solution issue = new Solution();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            issue.readFromLIst();
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                issue.removeItemsFromList();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        t2.start();
        t1.start();


        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.out.println("Final List: " + issue.list);

    }

}
```

> Removing: Item_0 READ: Item_1 READ: Item_2 READ: Item_3 READ: Item_4
>   READ: Item_5 READ: Item_6 READ: Item_7 READ: Item_8 READ: Item_9 READ:
>   Item_10 READ: Item_11 READ: Item_12 READ: Item_13 READ: Item_14 READ:
>   Item_15 READ: Item_16 READ: Item_17 READ: Item_18 READ: Item_19 READ:
>   Item_20 READ: Item_21 READ: Item_22 READ: Item_23 READ: Item_24 READ:
>   Item_25 READ: Item_26 READ: Item_27 READ: Item_28 READ: Item_29
>   Removing: Item_1 Removing: Item_2 Removing: Item_3 Removing: Item_4
>   Removing: Item_5 Removing: Item_6 Removing: Item_7 Removing: Item_8
>   Removing: Item_9 Removing: Item_10 Removing: Item_11 Removing: Item_12
>   Removing: Item_13 Removing: Item_14 Removing: Item_15 Removing:
>   Item_16 Removing: Item_17 Removing: Item_18 Removing: Item_19
>   Removing: Item_20 Removing: Item_21 Removing: Item_22 Removing:
>   Item_23 Removing: Item_24 Removing: Item_25 Removing: Item_26
>   Removing: Item_27 Removing: Item_28 Removing: Item_29 Final List: []

I got it working using **CopyOnWriteArrayList** (without **synchronized** block), but it seems to be having an overhead of creating a new list whenever the list is modified.

Am I missing something while using the sychronizedList to achieve the same result as that of CopyOnWriteArrayList?

Comment: One thread removing items from the list and the other thread keep reading until it's empty. Is this based on a real life scenario? What problem are you trying to solve with this design?

Comment: Seems producer-consumerish, and if so, then perhaps a list is not what you want to use

Comment: Perhaps you want to use a  blocking queue, `BlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();`

Comment: I am kind of experimenting it. But let's say a game character whose backpack contains 30 gold coins. while he is spending each of these, the same should be reflected in the scoreboard.

Comment: BlockingQueue, i'll try that.

Comment: Now it seems like backpack items should be a *bound* property, allowing listeners to be notified of state changes, such as by using a property change listener.

Comment: make sense.....

Answer (score 1):

For `synchronizedList`, you **have to** hold the lock while traversing it.

But since you are only doing remove-first and traversal on the list, you can consider using `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` instead. From the document of `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`:

> Iterators are weakly consistent, returning elements reflecting the state of the deque at some point at or since the creation of the iterator. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException, and may proceed concurrently with other operations.

So, you can traverse the deque without locking while the other thread is modifying it.

```
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque;

public class Solution {
    private Deque<String> list = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();

    public Solution() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            list.add("Item_" + i);
        }
    }

    private void removeItemsFromList() {
        String item = list.removeFirst();
        System.out.println("REMOVE " + item);
    }

    private void readFromLIst() {
        boolean isEmpty;
        do {
            isEmpty = true;
            Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("READ " + it.next());
                isEmpty = false;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } while (!isEmpty);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Solution issue = new Solution();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(issue::readFromLIst);

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                issue.removeItemsFromList();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        t2.start();
        t1.start();


        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.out.println("Final List: " + issue.list);

    }

}
```

Output:

```
READ Item_1
REMOVE Item_0
READ Item_2
REMOVE Item_1
READ Item_3
REMOVE Item_2
READ Item_4
REMOVE Item_3
READ Item_5
REMOVE Item_4
REMOVE Item_5
READ Item_6
READ Item_7
REMOVE Item_6
READ Item_8
REMOVE Item_7
READ Item_9
REMOVE Item_8
READ Item_10
REMOVE Item_9
READ Item_11
REMOVE Item_10
READ Item_12
REMOVE Item_11
READ Item_13
REMOVE Item_12
READ Item_14
REMOVE Item_13
READ Item_15
REMOVE Item_14
READ Item_16
REMOVE Item_15
READ Item_17
REMOVE Item_16
READ Item_18
REMOVE Item_17
READ Item_19
REMOVE Item_18
READ Item_20
REMOVE Item_19
REMOVE Item_20
READ Item_21
READ Item_22
REMOVE Item_21
REMOVE Item_22
READ Item_23
READ Item_24
REMOVE Item_23
REMOVE Item_24
READ Item_25
REMOVE Item_25
READ Item_26
READ Item_27
REMOVE Item_26
READ Item_28
REMOVE Item_27
READ Item_29
REMOVE Item_28
READ Item_29
REMOVE Item_29
Final List: []
```

Comment: I reduced the sleep timing of remove operation to 50ms. But it seems to be reading the data which is already removed from the list.                                      
REMOVE Item_0
READ: Item_1
REMOVE Item_1
REMOVE Item_2
READ: Item_2
REMOVE Item_3
REMOVE Item_4
READ: Item_3

Comment: REMOVE Item_2 READ: Item_2

Comment: Yeah, that's what `weakly consistent` means.

Comment: Ok. Then how do we deal with it? I think such a scenario is quite common in games and all.

Comment: What? I thought you were happy with reading whatever was left in the list after the modification. You see, only the definition of "after" is a bit vague for the iterator. We are dealing with a classic X-Y problem. I suggest you stop worrying about concurrent list/queue. Consider using state listeners.

Comment: "state listeners", agree with that. let me try.